# Init script for replicaSet in Mongo container

Tags: java, mongodb, docker, replicaset

I'm trying to test the ACID transaction for my replicaSet mongoDB. Is there anyway to initialize my mongoDB script in .js that look something like this

```
db.getCollection("myCollection").insert(
 ....
)
```

I've tried to initialize a mongo container for testing, in here I copied my init .js file into /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d the default folder to initialize script

```
GenericContainer mongodb = new GenericContainer("mongo:5")
                .withNetworkAliases("mongodbalias")
                .withCommand("--replSet myReplicaSet")
                .withEnv("MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE", "myDatabase")
                .withExposedPorts(27017)
                .withCopyFileToContainer(MountableFile.forClasspathResource("resources/db/initScript"), "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d");
```

However this came to an error:

```
    "errmsg" : "not master",
    "code" : 10107,
    "codeName" : "NotWritablePrimary"
```

this is due to my mongoDB is initialized with replicaSet